# Change the expiry time for welcome user notification message

Tags: users

Is there any way to change the expiry time for the welcome message sent after an administrator user created a new account for a user? By default, the login link included in the email is valid for a day, and I would like it to last seven days.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7:
Set user_password_reset_timeout variable (i.e. in settings.php, or strongarm):
i.e. in `settings.php`:

```
$conf['user_password_reset_timeout'] = '604800';
```

source : https://www.drupal.org/node/246029